# Huawei USB 3G modem not working on Lenovo G40-30 under Ubuntu 14.04 x64

Tags: 14.04, networking, usb-modem, 3g

I have a Huawei 3G USB modem which works fine on desktop Ubuntu 14.04 x32 without any efforts. It doesn't work on Ubuntu 14.04 x64 on Lenovo G40-30 laptop. Nothing happens when it is inserted in USB port.

How to make it work on this laptop?

Please note that I'm a Ubuntu beginner, I've found similar questions on this website but answers are different everywhere and I'm not sure which of those scary scripts should I copy in terminal.

```
myuser@myuser-NB:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 105b:e065  
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 5986:055d Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 12d1:1505 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E398 LTE/UMTS/GSM Modem/Networkcard
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

myuser@myuser-NB:~$ usb-devices

T:  Bus=01 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480 MxCh= 6
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev=03.19
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 3.19.0-51-generic xhci-hcd
S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:14.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=02 Cnt=01 Dev#=  7 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=12d1 ProdID=1505 Rev=00.00
S:  Manufacturer=HUAÿWEI TECHNOLOGIES
S:  Product=HUAWEI Mobile
S:  SerialNumber=ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=(none)

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=03 Cnt=02 Dev#=  2 Spd=480 MxCh= 4
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=05e3 ProdID=0608 Rev=85.37
S:  Product=USB2.0 Hub
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  3 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=ef(misc ) Sub=02 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=5986 ProdID=055d Rev=36.55
S:  Manufacturer=Bsion Corp.
S:  Product=Lenovo EasyCamera
S:  SerialNumber=200901010001
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=01 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo

T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=01 Cnt=02 Dev#=  4 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0bda ProdID=0129 Rev=39.60
S:  Manufacturer=Generic
S:  Product=USB2.0-CRW
S:  SerialNumber=20100201396000000
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=rtsx_usb

T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=02 Cnt=03 Dev#=  5 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=01 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=105b ProdID=e065 Rev=01.12
S:  Manufacturer=Broadcom Corp
S:  Product=BCM43142A0
S:  SerialNumber=38B1DBE02920
C:  #Ifs= 4 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=(none)
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=(none)
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=(none)
I:  If#= 3 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=fe(app. ) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=(none)

T:  Bus=02 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=5000 MxCh= 1
D:  Ver= 3.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=03 MxPS= 9 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0003 Rev=03.19
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 3.19.0-51-generic xhci-hcd
S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:14.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
```

**Update**

With reversiblean's help we couldn't find a fix for this problem. I decided to install x32 version of Ubuntu 14.04 where Wi-Fi and this 3G USB modem works out of the box. It doesn't work perfectly, sometimes it doesn't connect and I have to replug the modem, but at least it works like this.

I assume it's a bug in Ubuntu x64

Comment: The device is properly detected. Did you create 'Mobile Broadband' connection from the network manager?

Comment: I just created it. But it doesn't appear in top-right corner as an option. Only Ethernet and Wi-Fi are available to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Switching your device from 'storage-mode' to 'modem-mode' will do.

```
cd /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/
sudo wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/digidietze/usb-modeswitch-data/master/usb_modeswitch.d/12d1%3A1505
```

Open '/lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules'

```
sudo gedit /lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules
```

And add this line before the line reading `LABEL="modeswitch_rules_end"` in the end:

> ATTR{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="1505", RUN+="usb_modeswitch
>   '%b/%k'"

Just unplug and re-plug.

Wait for about 10 seconds and see if a menu entry appears on the network applet.

Comment: Didn't help(also rebooted). OS UI language is not English if this matters.

Comment: Can you come here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room